# MySql : Integrity contraint fails because of MyISAM and InnoDB mix. How to fix that safely?

Tags: mysql, django, innodb, myisam

I have a web site running on Django and MySql.

Part of the db tables are using InnoDB as engine and some other are using MyISAM.

There is no special reason for that. The project was started a long time ago and I think it is caused by a change in a configuration.

This cause some integrity constraint to fail when a InnoDB FK is referencing a MyISAM table. Changing the table from MyISAM to InnoDB fix the problem.

My problem is that this site is under production. It already has this mix of tables. There is a lot of tables.

Is there a clean and safe way to fix this problem? Do I have to change all MyISAM tables into InnoDB? Is there any risk to do that?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly take the web site offline and convert your MyIsam tables to InnoDb.  (Do back up the db first, of course.)

Your big quality risk on a production web site isn't changing a table's storage engine, though.  It's starting to enforce database integrity constraints while the system is in production.  You may find that you have a lot of data repair to do to allow the constraints to be enforced.

You are probably wisest to build a shadow copy of this system (web site and DB) and work through all your changes carefully.  Keep track of the commands and configuration changes you do on the shadow copy, so you can do them again on the live copy when you've proven that they work.  But there is some chance they won't work.

Shadow copies are easy in this age of virtual machines.